# Remove Substring with Regex Characters in Filename

Tags: regex, powershell, substring

so i'm trying to organize and clean up on how I download music. One of these ways is using a pluging for converting videos into MP3, though this usually leaves a watermark in the filename, which I'd like to remove via a Powershell Script.

So I essentially would have this "artist - songname[watermark.com].mp3"

I've looked into it and try to just get the brackets removed due to them being regex and i've had this done so far:

```
$removeMe = "[watermark.com]"
$list = Get-ChildItem *.mp3 | -replace '[[\]]',''
```

That's what I have so far before I get lost, It removes the brackets like so

```
Artist - Songnamewatermark.com.mp3
```

So I tried the same with

```
-replace 'watermark.com' yet it brings back the brackets.

Artist - Songname[watermark.com].mp3
```

I'm kind of struggling here, RegEx is not my forte, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A regex for this is extremely simple, but I can't figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: Instead of having a filename when I download to be "artist - songname[watermark.com].mp3" I run this powershell script to remove the substring '[watermark.com]' from the filename. So all that remains is "artist songname.mp3"

Comment: `\[[^\[\]]+\]` should do it.

Comment: Note that in case you need to remove a literal string `watermark.com`, you may use the string `.Replace` method, no need for a regex. Like `'Artist - Songname[watermark.com].mp3'.Replace($removeMe, '')`

Comment: Well the watermark includes the brackets in the filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use code:

```
-replace '\[[A-Za-z.]+\]',''
```